# How can I get (Node.js) MongoDB documents with a distinct value where some other value is the lowest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, distinct

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    name : 'a',
    value: 10,
    word : 'baz'
},
{
    name : 'a',
    value: 65,
    word : 'bar'
},
{
    name : 'a',
    value: 3,
    word : 'foo'
},
{
    name : 'b',
    value: 110,
    word : 'bar'
},
{
    name : 'b',
    value: 256,
    word : 'baz'
}
```

How do I perform a query that results in selecting the **full** documents where `name` is unique, and `value` is the lowest? E.g.:

```
{
    name : 'a',
    value: 3,
    word : 'foo'
},
{
    name : 'b',
    value: 110,
    word : 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) operator in the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to achieve what you want using a query like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$name", value:{$min:"$value"}}}, 
    {$limit:2}
])
```

This query would return:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "b",
                        "value" : 110
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "a",
                        "value" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

You can also include a [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) phase in the pipeline if you want your results to be sorted.

**EDIT:** You can select other elements not included in $group's _id field using a neat little trick.  First sort the documents and then use the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort:{value:1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$name", value:{$min:"$value"}, word:{$first:"$word"}}} 
])
```

This query would return:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "b",
                        "value" : 110,
                        "word" : "bar"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "a",
                        "value" : 3,
                        "word" : "foo"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What does `$limit:2` do? And how do I select another value from the document that matched `$min`?

Comment: [`$limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) restricts the number of documents included in the result (or rather the number of documents passed through to the next phase of the aggregation pipeline).

Comment: [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) only matches the lowest value in the group.  You cannot get more than one value using $min

Comment: I understand the limitation of `$min`, but I want to select the _complete_ documents. It's my fault that I didn't provide a correct example with more values in the documents. I've updated my question. Maybe a different approach gets the job done?

Comment: BTW - if you know a way to do that, don't remove your old answer. It's valuable as it is. Add to your answer in stead (or make a new one).

Comment: I've posted a different approach to achieve what you want.  See if that helps.

Comment: I haven't tried this (yet) but on first glance, wouldn't the `$group` section in the pipeline throw away `word`? (Sent from mobile)

Comment: Since we are using the `$first` operator to include `word`, it would show up.  In my query, I had missed to include `word`.  It's fixed now.  Give it a shot.

Comment: This is clever, thanks. I've accepted your answer. The only thing __(1)__ that concerns me with this method (memory and speed wise) is possibly selecting a million records, sorting a million records, throwing away 0.99 million records and having 10.000 records as a result (which I can `limit()`). Do you have any thoughts on that? If I put an `index` on `value`, can I skip the sorting? And __(2)__ is sorting on `name` necessary?

Comment: **(1)** If it's possible for your to filter out records using a $match phase in the beginning, that'll help.  If that's not the case, creating an index on the sort field should greatly help too.  May be you can run some experiments and post on SO if you have issues :) **(2)** You are correct!  The sort on `name` wasn't required.  My bad!